# Construct an explicit homotopy from $\gamma^2$ to the trivial loop in $SO(3)$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups

The fundamental group of $SO(3)$ is generated by $\gamma(\theta)$ rotation of degree $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$ in the first two coordinates. Construct a homotopy from $\gamma^2$ to the trivial loop.

My question since I have very little previous knowledge of algebraic topology is first how this rotation generates the fundamental group (which I believe is the group of homotopy classes of loops) and second what is the loop represented by $\gamma^2$?

Ok, from the comment I guess the problem is to get a continuous map $f(\theta, t), t \in [0, 1]$ such that $f(\theta, 0) = \gamma^2 (\theta) = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) & 0 \\ -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \theta \in [0, 4\pi]$ and $f(\theta, 1) = \mathbb{diag}\{1,1,1\}$, and I don't think I can scale the angle since I have to have $4\pi t$ be an integer multiple of $2\pi$ for $f(\theta, t)$ to remain a loop.

Comment: A quick answer to your second question: given two loops $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$, the loop $\gamma_1\gamma_2$ is the loop you get from going around $\gamma_1$ and then going around $\gamma_2$ (i.e. the group operation is concatenation). So, $\gamma^2$ is the loop you get from traversing $\gamma$ twice.

Comment: Not an answer, but still you might be interested to know that the fact that $\gamma^2$ is null homotopic is the reason the belt/mug trick works. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rzt_byhgujg and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Idea*: For $2\pi\le\theta\le4\pi$ and $0\le t\le\tfrac{1}{2}$, rotate the axis of rotation around a perpendicular axis by $2\pi t$, so that at $t=\tfrac{1}{2}$ the loop for $2\pi\le\theta\le4\pi$ is the reverse of the loop for $0\le\theta\le2\pi$. Then for $\tfrac{1}{2}\le t\le1$ you can shrink all the angles of rotation to $0$. Do you see what I mean, visually?